# How to run function with broadcastreceiver in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a function in activity I want to run this function with `broadcastreceiver`. How can I make this?

```
public class Myclass extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

This is my `broadcastreceiver` class I want to run function which is in my `activty` please tell me with some code how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If the method you want to execute needs your activity instance, then you can register the broadcast receiver inside your activity, so it can access your activity's state and functions.
In your Activity "onCreate" method:

```
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("Your Intent action here");
    intentFilter.addAction("Another action you want to receive");

    final BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            theFunctionYouWantToExecute();
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And in your "onDestroy" method:

```
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

Keep in mind that in this case your broadcast receiver has full access to your activity state, BUT it's lifecycle will be conditioned to the activity lifecycle.
Another option you have is to declare your activity method as static, so you can execute it in any part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quote naif, but you could call a static method in your activity.

In your activity you declare the method like this:

```
public static <return_type> yourMethod(<input_objs>){
....
Your code
....
}
```

In the receiver you can use this function just calling:

```
YourActivityClass.yourMethod(<input_objs>);
```

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just create your method in the `Activity` and using Activity's instance call that method. Remember that your method inside your `Activity` should be not private.

```
public class Myclass extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        new YourActivity().yourFunction(); 
    }
}
```

If you want to create a static method inside your `Activity` then

```
   public class Myclass extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            YourActivity.yourFunction(); 
        }
    }
```

To trigger the `Broadcast`, you have to pass an `Intent`. If you want to trigger it from any `Activity` then

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

If you want to trigger the `Broadcast` from a `Fragment` then

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: how to create static method?in activity?

Comment: Use keyword _static_ before your method return type

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an interface in `Myclass` and implement it in your `MainActivity`

```
public class Myclass extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public interface MyClassInterface {
        void onMyClassReceive();
    }

    private MyClassInterface mListener;

    public Myclass(MyClassInterface mMyClassInterface) {
        mListener = mMyClassInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mListener.onMyClassReceive();
    }
}
```

Then in your `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity implements Myclass.MyClassInterface {

private mMyClass Myclass = new Myclass(this);
    @Override
    public void onMyClassReceive() {
        // Do stuff when Myclass.onMyClassReceive() is called,
        // which will be called when Myclass.onReceive() is called.
    }
}
```